# Clicking list box items does not adjust the fields to correctly display the fields of the record

Tags: vba, ms-access

In access 2007-2016

I created a form based on a table "Publishers" with 5 fields displayed as: pub_id, pub_name, city, state, country.
In design tab i added a listBox to the form, which got its values from the option "Find a record on my form based on the value I selected in my list box."
I selected pub_id as the key column and pub_name as the column
I changed the control source of the listbox to pub_id. but now i have the problem of whenever i try to navigate through the listbox by clicking on listbox items, the pub_name, city, state, and country do not update. Also, further clicking on any items causes the error "Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit".
Here is the problem below, 4 fields are still showing data for the first pub_id. Although the pub_id has been updated correctly. [the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7lRX.png)

Comment: Control used to enter/select filter criteria should be UNBOUND (no control source), otherwise you change data in record.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do with the listbox.  Here is a youtube example though I have issues with them referencing form controls : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkmEu6Wh534